# Maya Python GUI Rotate Sphere

Tags: python, user-interface, maya, face

*(New Coder)* I'm trying it create a basic GUI which allows the user to create a sphere and choose the radius and rotation. I managed to do the radius however i am a bit stuck with the rotation; the xform command. Like i said the radius is working but not the rotation.

Heres the GUI at the moment: https://gyazo.com/5f3626443334da1abdecaea434fe4e03

Any help appreciated:)

Heres my code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def shapeTool ():
    ram = 'RenamerWin'
    if cmds.window(ram, q = True, exists =True):
        cmds.deleteUI(ram)

    ram = cmds.window("RenamerWin",t = "Shape Tool", w=300, h=300)
    cmds.columnLayout(adj = True)
    cmds.separator(h=20)
    cmds.text("Welcome to the Shape Creator")
    cmds.separator(h=20)

    sphR = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Radius", min =0, max = 10, field = True)
    sphA = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Rotate", field = True)

    def mySphere(_):
        mySphereRadius = cmds.intSliderGrp(sphR , q= True,value =True)
        mySphereRotate = cmds.intSliderGrp(sphA , q= True,value =True)
        finalSphere = cmds.polySphere(r=mySphereRadius, n = "mySphere")
        finalSphere = cmds.xform( r=True, ro=(0, 90, 0) )

    cmds.button(l = "Create a Sphere",c=mySphere)
    cmds.showWindow(ram)

shapeTool()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your rotate function will always rotate the new sphere 90 degrees in Y. Is that the intent? it ignores the rotate slider.
2. As written, it will rotate the sphere you create -- but for clarity and to understand what's really going on you might want to do this:

   finalSphere, finalShape = cmds.polySphere(r=mySphereRadius, n = "mySphere")
     cmds.xform(finalSphere, r=True, ro=(0, mySphereRotate, 0))

Comment: Thanks. When i run it however i get an "Invalid syntax error"